# Custom Build Activity Not Running

Tags: tfs, workflow-foundation, tfsbuild, workflow-activity

I have a custom build activity, but it's not executing. I've put it in try-catch block which catches **Sysytem.Exception** in my build template, and first line of overriden execute method is throwing **Sysytem.Exception**. On the log I see only line with the name of my custom activity! Any guesses?

```
     protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
     {
        throw new System.Exception("This is hello messasge");
        ...
     }
```

Comment: I don't understand, your custom code throws an exception, and the workflow sees that exception.  What do you expect it to do differently?

Comment: The workflow did't see the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out! I have specified path to assembly with my custom activities in the properties of build controller, but a had assembly with the same name in GAC. So, I suppose, TFS was using not my assemly, but assembly from GAC.